# Socket IO Server is Sending Messages But Client is not Receiving the Message

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am having a weird experience.

I have a Socket IO Server implemented in Spring Boot. When the server sends an event I inspected this in the Chrome Network tab and I discovered that the events are really being sent, but my react js client is not logging the events that were sent. What could be wrong.

Here is my client:

```
 const initSocketIO = () => {
        socket.on("connect", (data: any) => {
            console.log("I am connected!");
            socket.io.emit("test", "Test Data!");
        })
        socket.on("game", (data: any) => {
            console.log("New SocketIO Data Received as: ");
        });
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            console.log("I've being disconnected");
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        initSocketIO();
        return () => {
            socket.off("game")
        }
    }, [loaded]);
```

Inside the Network Tab in Chrome, I can see that whenever the Server Sends a message, it comes in but the code above is not firing....

Here are the messages as seen under the Network tab on Chrome[image]

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

try putting `socket.on` inside `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connect", (data: any) => {
        console.log("I am connected!");
        socket.io.emit("test", "Test Data!");
    })
    socket.on("game", (data: any) => {
        console.log("New SocketIO Data Received as: ");
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("I've being disconnected");
    });
    return () => {
        socket.off("game")
    }
}, [loaded]);
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it still didn't work.